# How to preserve new lines when doing: #include "file"

Tags: c

The file has empty new lines.

```
"a"
""
"b"
""
"c"
```

File is included into the program via the following method

```
fputs (
#include "file"
,stdout
);
```

actual result:

```
abc
```

Expected result:

```
a

b

c
```

Comment: `""` --> `"\n\n"`

Comment: You can't. The empty new lines are not *within* the string, they're outside it. Only the stuff that is in `""` gets concatenated into the string literal.

Comment: By "result", do you mean output when the program is run? Then it has nothing to do with the #include.

Comment: Your usage of `#include` (inside an expression) is legally possible, but against most conventions.

Comment: I wonder why no one asked... *Why*?

Comment: Pro tip: When you (think you) have a problem with the preprocessor and #includes, first try to put everything in a single file, to see if it really is a preprocessor problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. My only guess is that the file OP includes is generated by some external tool.

Comment: Try to ge the idea of the `#include` directive and the preprocessor in general. This is an awful coding style. For this one, your strings are missing newlines. This is definitively an XY-problem.

Comment: @WoodD: you should **edit your question** to motivate it (and explain why you are coding so). As Olaf commented, your question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 3):

C merges string literals separated by whitespace. When you write

```
"a"
""
"b"
""
"c"
```

C compiler merges them into `"abc"`; you cannot detect the difference between the two sources once the code is compiled.

If you want line breaks, insert them into your string literals explicitly:

```
"a\n"
"\n"
"b\n"
"\n"
"c"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 fputs (
 #include "file"
 ,stdout
 );
```

is legal, but poor taste and against most coding conventions.

What happens is well explained by [dashblinkenight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377000/841108), that I won't repeat.

However, I would suggest another approach. Modify your build system (e.g. your `Makefile`  if using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) to *generate* a better (and prettier) `file.inc` which would contain complete statements, perhaps a succession of

```
WRITELINE("a");
WRITELINE("");
WRITELINE("b");
WRITELINE("");
```

then, *before* your `#include "file.inc"` add in your C file:

```
#define WRITELINE(Lin) do { fputs(Lin,fil); fputc('\n', fil); } while(0)
```

(this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/841108) has good answers explaining why I want to use `do{` ... `}while(0)` ....)

You could *generate* easily such a `fil.inc` (perhaps from your `fil`, with some `make` rule invoking `sed` or something else).

PS. Actually, generating C code is a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with the answer above, but you may also want to add `"\r"`.  Some systems require it.  This character will be the carriage return (13).  So you would place `"\n\r"` between characters.

Comment: No, notably because on those systems you could `fopen` in *text* mode, not *binary* mode.

Comment: You should never add `\r` if you want a newline! If you have a broken system which uses `"\r\n"`, leave it to the file functions as @BasileStarynkevitch wrote.

Comment: The two commands are related to typewriters, but still have some application to terminal applications.  `"\n"` indicates that a new line is needed, so in the absence of `"\r"` the terminal should place the character in the column to the right of the prior character and on the next row.  `"\r"` indicates that the typing should resume at the beginning of the current line, so in the absence of `"\n"`, characters should begin overwriting characters at the beginning of a row.  If the string is being communicated serially, it is important to include both in some applications.

Comment: [link] https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/basic-terminology-

Comment: @JonathonS: The stdio library automatically converts \n to \r\n for text streams in systems that requires it. It is only in very unusual circumstances, such as when the file is opened in binary mode, or when writing directly to the file descriptor, that you have to add the carriage return yourself. Not in this case, when writing to stdout.

Comment: That's probably correct.  I am working with an embedded system.  I am using customized functions for transmitting data to a serial port for efficiency.